# How to concatenate a columns in pandas

Tags: pandas

My data set is below

```
Name,ID
Ma,22
Hu,33
```

My code its adding all lines and going through next line, its not fine
`data['New_Name'] = data['Name'] + str(data_final_x['ID'])`

Expected out

```
Name,ID,New_Name
Ma,22,Ma 22
Hu,33,Hu 22
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`str(series)` returns representation of the whole series. You want

```
data['New_Name'] = data['Name'] + ' ' + data['ID'].astype(str)
```